# NGINX Reverse Proxy - выбор сервера по хешу от части URL

Tags: nginx

Возможно ли средствами nginx выбирать сервер по хешу от части URL. К примеру, у меня есть запросы вида http://host/room/123456/invite, http://host/room/123456/user?id=2... Я хочу чтобы все запросы с одинавым номером комнаты приходили на один и тот же сервер, потому что данные комнаты кешуруются на нем.

С текущей конфигурацией выбор сервера зависит от всего URL:

```
upstream backend {
       hash $uri;
       server 127.0.0.1:2001;
       server 127.0.0.1:2002;
}
```

Пока что вижу только вариант с модификацией [upstream_hash](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_hash_module.c) модуля.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все-таки решил проблему, рабочая конфигурация:

```
upstream backend {
        hash $room;
        server 127.0.0.1:2001;
        server 127.0.0.1:2002;
}
server {
        location ~ ^/(?<room>[a-zA-Z0-9]+) {
        proxy_pass http://backend ;
}
```